# Using blocks as callback handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I want to use blocks as callback handler, but I am not sure what I am doing is proper or not because my app is crashing.
Here is what I am doing:

In my FirstViewController I am calling method of class FirstModel to get data from server as follows:

```
//In FirstViewController.m
[aFirstModelObj retreiveDataWithCallBackHandler:^(NSDictionary *responseDict){

   //Data is received so we can proceed...
}];

//In FirstModel.m
typedef void(^newBlock)(NSDictionary *);
    newBlock theBlock;

-(void)retreiveDataWithCallBackHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *))aBlock
{
    //Saving "aBlock" for further use..
    theBlock = aBlock;

    //Server Processor will retrieve data using URL asynchronously,
   //initializing ServerProcessor object and providing FirstModel its delegate,so that when data is received in ServerProcessor class FirstModel's receivedResponse method will get called.

    serverProcessorObj.delegate = self;

}

-(void)receivedResponse:(NSDictionary *)responseDict
{
   //once data is received call block,
   theBlock(responseDict);
}
```

My app is crashing because I am loosing delegate. When I call [delegate receivedResponse:response] from ServerProcessor it says exc bad access. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is "theBlock" - just a simple ivar? it should be "copy" property

Comment: This would also crash if `theBlock` were `nil`.

Comment: `theBlock` should not be there at all.

Comment: Have you checked so your ServerProcessorObject call in done async? If not maybe your ServerProceessorObject calls the delegate before its set.

Comment: Pavel's right on. Blocks are objects, so you need to treat them as such with respect to memory management. See http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking that the block is not nil (as per comments), perhaps it has something to do with:

The above approach will only allow you to process one asynchronous request at a time. Are you trying to process concurrent requests? A subsequent request will override the block for a previous request. This could cause problems.

If you need to support concurrent requests, you'll need retain each of the blocks for a currently running request, so that the can be invoked upon completion of the request.

If you were passing on object in, such as:

```
retreiveDataForCustomer:(Customer*)customer onSuccess:(void (^)(NSDictionary*))success
```

. . . then I would suggest create a property or [associative reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject) on the customer object to retain the block. However as your call has no parameters, you'll have to find another way of tracking which block goes with which delegate invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your code.

```
-(void)retreiveDataWithCallBackHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *))aBlock
{
    //Saving "aBlock" for further use..
    theBlock = Block_copy(aBlock);

    //Server Processor will retrieve data using URL asynchronously,
    //initializing ServerProcessor object and providing FirstModel its delegate,so that when data is received in ServerProcessor class FirstModel's receivedResponse method will get called.

    serverProcessorObj.delegate = self;

}

-(void)receivedResponse:(NSDictionary *)responseDict
{
   //once data is received call block,
   if (theBlock)
       theBlock(responseDict);
}
```